# Catch ANR globally in Application

Tags: android

i just want to know is there any way to get ANR notifications either through triggering any  event functions or atleast catch it .despite running long process in separate thread there are  possibities of ANR.so all i want to do is  when app detects ANR it has to handle some functions automatically.please assist me how to achieve this.thank you.

Comment: "despite running long process in separate thread there are possibities of ANR" -- then fix the bugs in your app.

Comment: I think that [my answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17883242/1269640) can help you

Answer (score 0):

you could use a service (preferably a foreground service) that listens to the logs (using a thread) , and if there is a log that indicate the ANR , handle it.

here's a small sample of an app that causes ANR:

```
...
findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
  {
    @Override
    public void onClick(final View v)
      {
      try
        {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        }
      catch(final InterruptedException e)
        {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
  });
...
```

here's the log that i got from the logcat when i got the ANR:

```
08-03 13:02:37.746: E/ActivityManager(158): ANR in com.example.anr (com.example.anr/.MainActivity)
08-03 13:02:37.746: E/ActivityManager(158): Reason: keyDispatchingTimedOut
08-03 13:02:37.746: E/ActivityManager(158): Load: 6.19 / 2.37 / 0.86
08-03 13:02:37.746: E/ActivityManager(158): CPU usage from 5598ms to 0ms ago:
08-03 13:02:37.746: E/ActivityManager(158):   2.6% 158/system_server: 2.5% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 86 minor
08-03 13:02:37.746: E/ActivityManager(158):   0.5% 298/com.android.phone: 0.3% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 15 minor
08-03 13:02:37.746: E/ActivityManager(158):   0% 35/rild: 0% user + 0% kernel
08-03 13:02:37.746: E/ActivityManager(158): 4.6% TOTAL: 3.9% user + 0.6% kernel
08-03 13:02:37.746: E/ActivityManager(158): CPU usage from 2029ms to 2654ms later:
08-03 13:02:37.746: E/ActivityManager(158):   11% 158/system_server: 4.8% user + 6.4% kernel / faults: 2 minor
08-03 13:02:37.746: E/ActivityManager(158):     11% 192/InputDispatcher: 4.8% user + 6.4% kernel
08-03 13:02:37.746: E/ActivityManager(158):     1.6% 163/Compiler: 1.6% user + 0% kernel
08-03 13:02:37.746: E/ActivityManager(158):     1.6% 193/InputReader: 0% user + 1.6% kernel
08-03 13:02:37.746: E/ActivityManager(158): 18% TOTAL: 9.3% user + 9.3% kernel
```

so , yes , i think it's possible.

Comment: It will not be possible as of Jelly Bean, as you are not be able to read the logs from other processes or the OS. Besides, reading the logs is not part of the Android SDK.

Comment: correct.since i don't have JB , i can't see if there are any workarounds for this. they said in the google IO that even though now it won't work , it's ok to read the logs of your own app , so i don't know if such a thing is considered to be inside the app (i guess it's not).anyway , this solution is a workaround from the start . it should work for about 99% of the devices currently .